# Variable initializer is redundant

Tags: java, android

I'm at a complete loss for what is going on. I'm just trying to supply my spinner with an array as per documentation and I can't get past these 4 warnings:

Variable `spinnerY` initializer `findViewById(R.id.spinnerYear)` is redundant

As well as adapter `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.year, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)`

Then `findViewById` can't be resolved and finally, `this` is the wrong 1st argument type.

As a bonus question, my fragment has 3 spinners so will I have to duplicate this for each one? Any help with these is *very* much appreciated.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_vehicle, container, false);

    Spinner spinnerY = findViewById(R.id.spinnerYear);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.year, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerY.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

Comment: Don't know why you're getting those weird *warnings*. What you should be getting is *error* **Unreachable code**, because the code is after an unconditional `return` statement.

Comment: I would invaladite cache and restart Android studio. File-> invalidate cache/restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the spinner from the view you inflated. `this` will denote the `Fragment` instance but you need to supply `Activity` context so use `getContext()` to get the `Activity` context.

Use this code

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_vehicle, container, false);

Spinner spinnerY = rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerYear);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(), R.array.year, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerY.setAdapter(adapter);
return rootView;
}

 @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```